# Getting Exent of Queried Results using ArcGIS Python API?

Tags: arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-python-api

Im trying to use the ArcGIS Python API to query a few results and gather the extent, I can query the results fine but as soon as I try to extract the extent I retrieve empty results.

Using one of the samples servers, heres my code:

```
import arcgis.gis
gis = GIS()

t = 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/DamageAssessment/FeatureServer/0'
layer = FeatureLayer(t, gis)

results = layer.query(where='1=1', return_extent_only=True)
```

After I print results I get the following

```
{"features": [], "fields": []}
```

Am I missing something? Seems all to easy up until this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to 1.5.2 API Resolved the issue, must have been a bug

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer
gis = GIS()

t = 'https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/DamageAssessment/FeatureServer/0'
layer = FeatureLayer(t, gis)

results = layer.query(where='1=1', return_extent_only=True)
print(results)
```

The only differences between our code are the import statements - maybe adjust those and retry?